# Assigning rvalue references while assigning string

Tags: c++, string, stdmove

I am learning about rvalue references and my brain is probably all over the place. But I wanted to test the std::move and rvalue references and below is the code snippet

```
string s1 = "hello";
{
    string&& s2 = std::move(s1);
    cout << s2 << endl;
}

cout << s1 << endl;
```

The output is the same in both the cases. "hello"

I was hoping that inside the block when creating s2, it would've called the move assignment operator, thus making sure that s1 didnt point to anything, but that didnt happen.

My rational is that string is carrying a pointer to char inside of it, so when the move pointer is called, it will move the memory allocation from  Thus when I move from s1 to s2, printing s1 should cause problems.

What did I do wrong in my understanding.

Comment: You're ignoring the fact that `s2` is a _reference_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing,

```
string&& s2 = std::move(s1);
```

isn't an assignment at all; it's an initialization.

And it's initialization of a reference, not an object.  There is only one `std::string` in your program, named `s1`.  Since you declared `s2` as a reference, it refers to some other object - here that's `s1`.  So no move constructor or move assignment operator needs to be called at all, and `s1` can't be changed.

If you wrote instead

```
string s2 = std::move(s1);
```

then this would in fact create a second `std::string` object named `s2`.  It gets initialized using the move constructor.

Or if the `=` is used on an object previously declared, not to introduce an initializer right after a declaration, then it's a true assignment:

```
string s2;
s2 = std::move(s1);
```

Here `s2` is first created using the `std::string` default constructor, and then modified using the `std::string` move assignment operator.

But note that after a `std::string` move constructor or move assignment operator, the contents of the "moved-from" object are *unspecified*.  In some cases, the Standard says exactly what a move operation will do, often making the moved-from object empty.  But when not otherwise specified, it says only that the object is in a "valid but unspecified state".  And `std::string` doesn't add any specific requirements, so the unspecified state is the result.  So printing `s1` after this might result in anything at all.  (Practically speaking, if the `std::string` implementation uses the Small String Optimization, you might find that `s1` has not been changed.)

Answer (score 1):

s2 is still a reference, that means that no other constructor or assignment operator was called in your code. You can use s2 to call a move contructor or a move assignment. In that constructor, the move magic will happen (even though the old string might still contain the original text after that).

```
string s1 = "hello";
string&& s2 = std::move(s1);  // s2 is a reference
string s3 = std::move(s2);    // now we moved
```

Comment: An rvalue-reference is still an lvalue. So to call a move constructor or assignement you still need to use `std::move`.

Comment: @hansmaad Then I could've probably just done string s2 = std:move(s1), would that have done what I intended to do?

Comment: @hansmaad thanks for you answer, but did I really need to do the second line of code at all then?

Comment: @Kraken No, of course not... `string s2(move(s1));` or `string s2 = move(s1)` is also possible.